# Warning when dispatching ShowToastEvent

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I'm trying to follow the pattern in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_toast for displaying a toast message. However, whenever I do I get the following warning:

[LWC warning]: Invalid event type "lightning__showtoast" dispatched in element . Event name should only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters.

My code is:

```
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

{...}

handleFormError(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
        title: labelStandardErrorResult,
        message: event.detail,
        variant: 'error',
        mode: 'sticky'
    }));
}
```

Comment: Did you pull any code from lwc-recipes? I see reference to this "lightning__showtoast" there https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/platformShowToastEvent.js#L7

Comment: We're using lwc-jest which has pretty much the same code. So I guess I need to ask a question on their repo. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I'd also check that you've pulled all necessary code that is needed.